# Writing a matrix in excel

Tags: python, excel, matrix

I am trying to write an excel file from a python script.

I tried to make it with a 24x32 matrix (12 for all the months and one blank column and 32 for all possible days plus 1 more row for the name of the month on the top row)

I made a dictionary with all the month names and this year's month's length like this

`months = {"JANUARY": 31, "FEBRUARY": 29, "MARCH": 31, "APRIL": 30, "MAY": 31, "JUNE": 30, "JULY": 31, "AUGUST": 31, "SEPTEMBER": 30, "OCTOBER": 31, "NOVEMBER": 30, "DECEMBER": 31}`

And I wrote this function that writes to the excel file, but I get an error that I am trying to overwrite a cell and I can't understand what to do

```py
    def write_to_excel():
        months = {"JANUARY": 31, "FEBRUARY": 29, "MARCH": 31, "APRIL": 30, "MAY": 31, "JUNE": 30, "JULY": 31, "AUGUST": 31, "SEPTEMBER": 30, "OCTOBER": 31, "NOVEMBER": 30, "DECEMBER": 31}

        # Create Workbook
        workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
        # Create new sheet
        sheet = workbook.add_sheet("Sheet 1")

        column = 0
        if column % 2 == 0:
            for month in range(len(months.keys())):
                sheet.write(0, column, [*months.keys()][month])
                for date in range(1, int([*months.values()][month]) + 1):
                    sheet.write(date, column, f"{date}/{month}/2020")
        else:
            column += 1
```

This is the error I get:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user's_name/Desktop/app's_folder/app's_name.py", line 248, in <module>
    main_window()
  File "C:/Users/user's_name/Desktop/app's_folder/app's_name.py", line 240, in main_window
    response = approve_applications(raw_message)  # if it is get the email's information and project it on the window to be approved or denied
  File "C:/Users/user's_name/Desktop/app's_folder/app's_name.py", line 134, in approve_applications
    write_excel_file()
  File "C:/Users/user's_name/Desktop/app's_folder/app's_name.py", line 17, in write_excel_file
    sheet.write(column, 0, [*months.keys()][month])
  File "C:\Users\user's_name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\xlwt\Worksheet.py", line 1088, in write
    self.row(r).write(c, label, style)
  File "C:\Users\user's_name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\xlwt\Row.py", line 235, in write
    StrCell(self.__idx, col, style_index, self.__parent_wb.add_str(label))
  File "C:\Users\user's_name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\xlwt\Row.py", line 154, in insert_cell
    raise Exception(msg)
Exception: Attempt to overwrite cell: sheetname='Sheet 1' rowx=0 colx=0
```

Under the month's name I want to write every day that it has like this `day/month/2020`

So the output should be:

[image: And so on for each month]

The month's name doesn't have to be a combined cell, I don't know if that helps in any way, and the sundays, don't have to be colored.

If someone could help I would appreciate it, thanks in advance.

Comment: You appear to be using some module(s) you have not identified.

Comment: Store your data in a pandas dataframe and then exporting to excel is easy: pd.to_excel(file_path).

Comment: @TaxpayersMoney could you please answer to this question because I don't have much experience with pandas

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
with pd.ExcelWriter('file_name.xlsx') as w:
    jan = pd.Series(pd.to_datetime(pd.date_range(start='1/1/2020', end='1/31/2020'))).dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
    jan.to_excel(w, startcol=1)
    feb = pd.Series(pd.to_datetime(pd.date_range(start='2/1/2020', end='2/29/2020'))).dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
    feb.to_excel(w, startcol=4)
```

Comment: Repeated for each month?

Comment: Yeah, not quite sure why you want each month in a new column. Would be easy to create a single Series with all the dates. Then you'd just set the start date as 1st Jan and end date as 31 dec and you could output a single column with all the dates. But you may have a reason for separate cols. It gets a bit messy with separate cols because pandas doesn't like making a dataframe with cols of different lengths.

Comment: Could I make a dataframe that is 24x32 exactly, set the remaining days of the months that have less than 31 days to NaN and then replace NaN with a ""?